# How make Android x86 6.0 RC1 32bit look like a tablet with no mouse

Tags: touchscreen, virtualization, mouse, virtualbox, vmware

I produce training video, I don't write code, and I'm not that familiar with configuring Android\Linux. I'd appreciate your help. I have exhausted online searches to figure out the following.

**What I need**
I need an Android x86 (4.4 or greater, preferably 5 or later) virtual device (VMWare, VirtualBox, or something else) to *not* display a mouse pointer and act like a touchsreen device.

**Issue**
I've tried numerous things, found through Google searches, and the mouse pointer is always displayed. My customer does not want a pointer, he wants it to look like a phone\t

**My Environment**
Windows 10 Pro x64 host computer with or without a TouchScreen
VirtualBox 5.1 and VMWare Workstation 9
The virtual computers I've setup are Android x86 6.0 RC1 32bit running as a VirtualBox or VMWare virtual computer.

**What I've tried**
 - In Windows 10, the host for the virtual computers, disable and also uninstall my mouse. The mouse in the virtual Android computer was still present.
 - In VirtualBox and VMWare, added lines to their config files that are supposed to make the virtual computer a touchScreen.
 - In VirtualBox, enable & disable mouse integration.
 - In Android, deleted all *.idc files at /system/usr/idc except for AV??.idc, qwerty.idc, qwerty2.idc, and touch_dev.idc (which I copied from my phone), touch.idc (which I wrote following a posting online), and made sure all listed the touch.??? = touchScreen